# Apache camel send a simple message

Tags: java, message, apache-camel, mina

I have a simply camel MINA server using the JAVA DSL, and I am running like the example documented here:

- [Running Camel standalone and have it keep running in JAVA](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html)
- [MINA 2 Component](http://camel.apache.org/mina2.html)

I am trying to create a sample application hosted at "mina:tcp://localhost:9991" (aka MyApp_B) that sends a very simple message to a server hosted at "mina:tcp://localhost:9990" (aka MyApp_A).

I want is to send a simple message containing a String in the header (which is "Hellow World!") and with the address in the body.

```
public class MyApp_B extends Main{

    public static final String MINA_HOST = "mina:tcp://localhost:9991";

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        MyApp_B main = new MyApp_B();

        main.enableHangupSupport();

        main.addRouteBuilder(
                new RouteBuilder(){
                    @Override
                    public void configure() throws Exception {

                        from("direct:start")
                        .setHeader("order", constant("Hello World!"))
                        .setBody(constant(MINA_HOST))
                        .to("mina:tcp://localhost:9990");
                    }
                }
                );

        System.out.println("Starting Camel MyApp_B. Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");
        main.run();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MainApp_A {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.enableHangupSupport();
        main.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilder(){

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("mina:tcp://localhost:9990").bean(MyRecipientListBean.class, 
                        "updateServers").to("direct:debug");

                from("direct:debug").process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Received order: " +
                                exchange.getIn().getBody());
                    }
                });

            }

        });
        main.run(args);
    }

}
```

---

Bean used by MyApp_A:

```
public class MyRecipientListBean {

    public final static String REMOVE_SERVER = "remove";
    public final static String ADD_SERVER = "add";

    private Set<String> servers = new HashSet<String>();

    public void updateServers(@Body String serverURI, 
            @Header("order") String order){


        System.out.println("===============================================\n");
        System.out.println("Received " + order + "request from server " + serverURI + "\n");
        System.out.println("===============================================\n");

        if(order.equals(ADD_SERVER))
            servers.add(serverURI);
        else if(order.equals(REMOVE_SERVER))
            servers.remove(serverURI);
    }
}
```

I have done this code, however, the servers on the other side don't seem to receive anything. Therefore I have 2 questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Is there a better way to send simple message using Camel?

Comment: Is Camel outputting any logs? What is the address of your MINA server? You set the message content with port `9991`, but in the `.to` you gave port number `9000`.

Comment: The address of the other server is "mina:tcp://localhost:9990". The address of the server where this specific sample is running is "mina:tcp://localhost:9991".

In this case I am telling server 9990, that I am server 9991. Server 9990 is not printing anything.
The problem is that server "mina:tcp://localhost:9990" is not receiving anything from "mina:tcp://localhost:9991"

Comment: You have not provided enough of your code to see what is going on.

Comment: Fixed, I added all the code.Hope it is enough now =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyApp_A does NOT send any messages. You need to send a message to the direct endpoint to start the route.

You can also change direct to a timer component to have it trigger every X second etc.

*Added latest comment as requested:*

> yes and the direct route is also running. Its just that to send a
>   message to direct, you need to do that using Camel. direct is an
>   internal Camel component for sending messages between its endpoint
>   (routes). To send a message to it, you can use the producer template.
>   See chapter 7, section 7.7 in the Camel in Action book.

Comment: I am not understanding something right, so please correct me. MyApp_A, reads from "mina:tcp://localhost:9990", then it calls a bean method, and then it puts the message into the "direct:debug" queue.

After that, I read that queue and use a processor to print the messages. What is wrong with this?

Also, why should I need a timer? I mean, MyApp_A will activate the route once it receives a message from MyAPP_B correct?

Comment: No problem, it happens to the best :P I dont understand why the ("direct:start") route in MyApp_B is not being used. I mean, all routes in camel are automatically [auto started by default](http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html) right?

Comment: yes and the direct route is also running. Its just that to send a message to direct, you need to do that using Camel. direct is an internal Camel component for sending messages between its endpoint (routes). To send a message to it, you can use the producer template. See chapter 7, section 7.7 in the Camel in Action book.

Comment: Truly the templates are life savers. Thanks !
It would also be awesome if you could include your latest comment in your main answer so I can mark it :D