# How to send a message using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to create a sample application hosted at "mina:tcp://localhost:9991" that sends a very simple message to a server hosted at "mina:tcp://localhost:9990".

Now admittedly I have some problems understanding how to do this. My first approach was to create a class called Message, that has two fields: `String order` and `String host`. However, I am terribly confused on how to do this.

First I tried to follow the loadbalancer-example basing myself on the ReportGenerator and create a MessageGenerator class that could create a message and return it:

- http://camel.apache.org/loadbalancing-mina-example.html

However, there is a problem, I need parameters to create my Message, something that doesn't happen when creating the Report from the example:

```
//Message constructor
public Message(String order, String host){
    //constructor stuff
}
```

By reading Camel in Action I know how to use beans to call methods that have no parameters, however I still do not understand how I should use them to call a method that has several parameters (Am I forced to use processors?)

Then i realized that perhaps I am complicating things a little bit and there is an easier way to send messages. So I tried another approach that resulted in a small sample of code that does not work as well. I have created a separate question for that matter:

- [Apache camel send a simple message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865952/apache-camel-send-a-simple-message)

Obviously I am doing something wrong and I don't get what. So, I have 2 questions:

1. Manning's [Camel in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182366) defines an Easy way and a Hard way to use beans, but I did not understand the easy way of using beans with parameters. Can someone provide an example of it?
2. Is there a way to send a message composed of several fields in Camel (an easy way, without processors) that does not involve using beans? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to sends Messages in Camel. According to the help provided in the Camel forums, the two best are:

1. Using beans linked to POJOS and routes (example: http://camel.apache.org/loadbalancing-mina-example.html)
2. Using the Producer Template (docs: http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html)

Hope it helps someone one day.